# Audio dont work in external program with blender running

Tags: video

im trying to make a video of my workflow in blender, the problem is whenever blender is running..i cant get any program to run with audio..even youtube stops working ..is there anything that i cant maybe switch on in blender to make this work?

Comment: In the *Blender User Preferences* (Ctrl+Alt+U) you can switch the *Audio Dev*. in the *System* tab on the left side under *Sound*. Does this help? Which OS do you use?